# how to get Tag Cloud control to return more than 30 tags

Tags: xpages

I am using some of the tag cloud functionality in the discussion template released in July 2010... the ccTagCloud and ccTagCloudGroup custom controls.

I adjusted the maxTagLimit property from 25 to 50, but the maximum number of tags I am able to return is 30, probably due to the default view count of 30 in the category view.  But not being able to apply the trusty old "&count=" parameter anywhere in the properties, I have not found a way to get around this limitation.  Any ideas?

I noticed on the Lotus Notes and Domino wiki that the tagcloud there has 100.  I don't know if this is because the server default is set to 100 or not.

I don't think that upping the default view count server-wide is going to be an option, but will push on that door if all others are closed.

Answer (score 3):

The XPages Extension Library has a tagCloud control where you can set the maxTagLimit.

So if using Extension Library or Upgrade Pack 1 is an option, then I will suggest that you use this control instead.